# Django: Query involving Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models

I have models.py

```
class employees(models.Model):
  emp_id=models.PositiveIntegerField()
  emp_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
  emp_lname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
  emp_loc=models.CharField(max_length=5,choices=LOCATION)
  manager_id=models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)

class leave(models.Model):  
  employee = models.ForeignKey(employees, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
  start_date = models.DateField()
  end_date = models.DateField()
  status=models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=LEAVE_STATUS,default='P')
  ltype=models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=LEAVE_TYPE)

class notify(models.Model):
 sender_id=models.ForeignKey(leave, related_name='%(class)s_sendername')
 receiver_id=models.ForeignKey(leave,related_name='%(class)s_receivername')
 date_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 viewed=models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

I want the employee id of receiver_id as receiver_id is a foreign key...
    When I query 
        `notify.objects.filter(receiver_id__employee__emp_id=1`)

I am getting empty queryset but I want the tuples with emp_id=1.

Answer (score 0):

here `notify.objects.filter(receiver_id__employee__emp_id=1)` Make sure you have assigned emp_id field as it's not auto incremented field.

also try

```
notify.objects.filter(receiver_id__employee__id=1)
```